# Overloading operator[] for ArrayVector class

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector, operator-overloading

Hi i am having trouble writing this function:

```
int& ArrayVector::operator[](int index)
```

It must do the following

Return reference to index-th element of the array

If index is greater or equal to size of the array,
1. expand the array to cover up to (index+1) 
elements
 2. copy elements from old array to expanded array
 3. fill 0 for elements from n-th to (index-1)-th
 4. return the index-th element
 Also keep track the size of the array
Here is my class so far. I only need help with this function. Thanks!!

```
class ArrayVector {
private:
  int* data;
  int n;

public:
  ArrayVector() : data(NULL), n(0) { }

  int size() const {
    return n;
  }

  // print content of the array separated by “ “
  void print() {
    if (n == 0)
      return;

    // print from first element to second last element
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i)
      cout << data[i] << " ";

    // print last element
    cout << data[n-1] << endl;
  }

  // Return reference to index-th element of the array
  //  If index is greater or equal to size of the array,
  //    1. expand the array to cover up to (index+1) 
  //    elements
  //    2. copy elements from old array to expanded array
  //    3. fill 0 for elements from n-th to (index-1)-th
  //    4. return the index-th element
  //  Also keep track the size of the array

  int& operator[](const int index);

};
 


int& ArrayVector::operator[](int index) {
  // TODO
}
```

Comment: Ok, so what have your tried and if you are stuck which step do you have trouble with?

Comment: Your `print()` function can looks like `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) cout << data[i] << " ";` ...  no need for separating last element from `for loop` and if `n` is equal to `0` then statements in for loop will never happen so there is no need for checking for 0 array size

Comment: Oh and why implementing your own class when we already have `std::vector`?

Comment: @Quest it seems rather obvious from the very specific instructions that this is most likely an assignment of some sort

Answer (score 0):

you `operator[]` can looks like this:

```
int& ArrayVector::operator[](int index)
{
    if(index > 0 && index < n)
        return data[index];                // if index is in range, just return an element
    else{                                  // if not, 
        int *nData = new int[index+1];     // create a new, temporarily array with size index+1
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            nData[i] = data[i];            // copy data to our new aray
        delete[] data;                     // delete our old array

        for(int i = n; i < index+1; i++)
            nData[i] = 0;                  // fill newly created elements with 0

        data = nData;                      // set data to point to our new created array
        n = index+1;                       // set new data size

        return data[index];                    // return element with that index
    }
}
```

Comment: not really, the instructions he was given clearly specify that he should make room for enough elements if the vector is not yet large enough.

Comment: you almost got it. You allocate the wrong size (you should actually resize to fit at least `index+1` elements otherwise `vec[5] = 5; std::cout << vec[5];` would actually print 0 if the vector was smaller than 4). You also don't delete the old data. But I would really prefer it if you didn't just give the asker the full answer, since this seems to be an assignment

Comment: @PeterT Thanks for correcting me. I've updated my answer once again.

Comment: almost `if(index > 0 && index <= n)` should be `if(index > 0 && index < n)` and `return data[n];` should be `return data[n-1];` or better yet just `return data[index];`

Comment: @PeterT Thank you again :D I;m drunk so this is how it looks liek :D I will probably say thank you tomoerow agan...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64098/discussion-between-quest-and-petert).

Answer (score 0):

If index is within range- simply return the element.
Else :
Allocate a new array of size (n+(n-index+1)) into a temp pointer.
Copy first 'n' values using a for loop.
Put 0's in rest of the new array.
Set 'n' to the new size, delete old allocated array. Set 'data' to point to the new one.
Return element.

Answer (score 0):

You can have this

```
int& operator[](const int index){
    if(index>0 && index<n){
       return data[index];
    }
    else if(index>n){
      int *newData = new int[index+1];
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
          newData[i]=data[i];
      }
      for(int i=n;i<index+1;i++){
          newData[i]=0;
      }

      return newData[index];
    }else{
      return;
    }
```

};

Comment: You do not delete your old data and you do not set "data" to point to your newly created array. Also your function needs to return something( you can't just write `return;`